# Read Text file with null byte

Tags: windows, delphi, text

I have a text file with dos elements - hex(00) for example. I need to read it and convert it. I have tried to use `utf8toansi`, but this removes the whole line with hex(00). Are there any way to convert to text in the whole file ? 
I am using `win32`, `RadStudio2007`, `Delphi`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering :) I tried the last solution ( ConvertFileToDos) and it seems to be working nicely for me :)

Comment: Sorry, but I would never have guessed from the question that you wanted to convert a text file to a different format. Why using Delphi at all in that case? How about standard tools like tr, sed, awk?

Comment: Question summary and text is strongly misleading. All the OP wants to do is removing / replacing some chars from the file and write it out again. No need to do that with Delphi, use standard command line tools instead.

Comment: He mentions that he's on win32, so the mentioned tools are probably not available. 
Besides that, I can't think of anything that those tools can do that Delphi can't.

Comment: Tools are available, using MSys, Cygwin or GnuWin32. And even if Delphi can build similar tools - do you also build your hammer and pliers yourself? How does that saying go: "Those who do not understand Unix are condemned to reinvent it, poorly." (Henry Spencer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do...

```
procedure ConvertFileToDos(const aInFile,aOutFile:String);
var
  FileIn,FileOut:TextFile;
  C:AnsiChar;
  LineBreak:String;
begin
  LineBreak := #13#10;

  AssignFile(FileIn,aInFile);
  Reset(FileIn);

  AssignFile(FileOut,aOutFile);
  ReWrite(FileOut);

  while not EOF(FileIn) do
  begin
    Read(FileIn,C);
    if C=#0 then
      Write(FileOut,LineBreak)
    else
      Write(FileOut,C)
  end;

  CloseFile(FileIn);
  CloseFile(FileOut);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read it into a TMemoryStream, assign a PChar to the first address, and scan with a loop from 0 to Size - 1.  It's up to you of course what you want to do with the embedded #0 chars. Just ignore the #13 and add a string on each #10 that you encounter.

**EDIT:**

Something like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileStream: TStream;
  MemStream: TMemoryStream;
  P: PChar;
  s: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('file.txt', fmOpenRead);
  try
    MemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      MemStream.LoadFromStream(FileStream);
      P := PChar(MemStream.Memory);
      s := '';
      for i := 0 to MemStream.Size - 1 do begin
        case P[0] of
          #0: {};
          #10: begin
                 // do something with s
                 s := '';
               end;
          #13: {};
        else
          s := s + P[0];
        end;
        Inc(P);
      end;
    finally
      MemStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: TMemoryStream has a LoadFromFile method, obviating the intermediate TFileStream. Also, note that building up the string one character at a time is a bad idea. Store the start position and the length, and then use SetString.

Comment: I put this together in Delphi 4, where there is no TFileStream.LoadFromFile(), but this is of course a very good idea for later Delphi versions. Re 2) - it's a very good comment, and I would never do this in production code, I'd use two PChars. But I did not want to overcomplicate the example...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Delphi, but my guess is you probably need to open the file as a binary file and not a text file.  Then you can read the bytes directly and convert them to whatever you want.